# How to disable alerts/notification for operator confirmation on sms

Tags: 8.0, settings, lumia, sms

I have seen the settings where the sms delivery confirmation can be turned off, but what I need to do is to disable the notification that comes on top.

Any way to get this done on Windows Phone 8, I have a Nokia Lumia 720

Answer (score 3):

for this go to -->notification center 
then --> messaging and
--> remove the tick from show banner alerts

Answer (score 2):

When you enable delivery confirmation for SMS, the confirmation comes in as a text itself. Because this comes in as a text message, you cannot control when the `toasts` appear or disable them (just like for regular text messages).

[There are several users who have been requesting such a feature as you can see here.](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions?query=disable%20toast)

[There is also rumored to be an update to Windows Phone 8 coming soon- Windows Phone 8.1. There is potential that this may be addressed in one of the future versions.](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/purported-windows-phone-81-blue-leak-shows-notification-center-more)